# Deploying a background function to my Firebase Cloud Function and call it from the Client Android side

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to create a simple function and deploy it to my `node.js` server with the help of firebase Cloud Functions. The function just retrieves the current time:

```
const time = Date.now();
console.log(time);
module.exports = exports.currentTime  = time;
```

Since this function is not related to authentication, analytics, firestore, database, or any other firebase function, I'm not sure how to deploy it to my server.

From **my client Android side**, I'm trying to call the function with the help of:

```
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
```

But so far, I'm not seeing the function deployed in my Firebase function dashboard.

Comment: I am 100% uncertain what you're trying to do here.  Cloud Functions is 100% hosted inside Google cloud infrastructure.  It doesn't even look like you've declared a function in the way that's required by the `firebase-functions` module.  You can't make up your own types of functions - you have to choose one that's provided by Cloud Functions.

Comment: In my question I'm asking how to deploy the function to the server and I don't know how to do it. I did it successfully for another function that triggers when there is a writing happening in the realtime database using functions.database.ref(..).onWrite(). Since, this function is not related to any firebase function (it's basically just retrieving time), I did not know how to deploy it to the server. I'm from Android background so I'm sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: You can't deploy this function, since you haven't declared a type of function that Cloud Functions can trigger.  Maybe you need to use a callable function, you intend to invoke it from a client app?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable